# javascript doesn't load when json result is returned from action method in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json

I have my action method like this:

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();
        return Json(rm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

when I browse to that action method, I am not seeing any content that's on that view page being loaded. All I am seeing is this:

{"UserName":null,"Email":null,"Password":null,"ConfirmPassword":null}

RegisterModel contains those properties.

However, if I do this:

```
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return view();

    }
```

I can see the content on the view page loads when I browse to that same action.

Can anyone tell me how can I render all the javascript and html content on the view page when jsonresult is returned?

Comment: Well JSON is not HTML so..... ?

Comment: What output are you expecting by returning *Json(rm)*?  It looks exactly as expected to me-- a JSON string with empty properties (since you didn't set any of them).

Comment: well I have some javascript code on my view page like below:    $.getJSON(GetURL,
   function (data) {
       
       $.each(data, function (key, val) {
           var obj = {};
           obj["key"] = key;

           $.template("elementTemplate", element);
           $.tmpl("elementTemplate", obj).appendTo("#Container");

       });
   }); I use this to parse the json content and display in the format by using templates. But the problem here is, I am not seeing the above script being loaded?

Comment: Ok I think the problem you have is your trying to use the same action to render the page AND to render some other set of JSON that you are using to bind some javascript templating engine too, correct? If that is the case the answer is simple - Use two separate actions.

Comment: You are correct. This is what I have been doing.                       public ActionResult Register()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Register1()
        {
            RegisterModel rm = new RegisterModel();
            return Json(rm, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }so whenever I go to Register view, I get redirected to the Register1 action method through the javascript code above(where GETURL points to Register1 action method) and it works. But I would like it something that happens on first load instead of redirect to another action method

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone tell me how can I render all the javascript and html
>   content on the view page when jsonresult is returned?

`JsonResult` is a type of action result that serialize a model(Employee, Product..) into [Json](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) format and return to the client. `Json` is a type of format like xml. When you return Json you can't attach scripts, css or other stuff like that.

If you want to return html with css, javascript etc. then you should use the `ViewResult`(`reurn View()`). If you want to return a piece of html instead of a complete document you can use `PartialViewResult`(`return PartialView()`).